# Buggy collision 2D platform game

Tags: java, game-engine, collision

I'm building my first big project and I'm having trouble with the collision.
At first I used a println command in the collision detection and it worked great,so the problem is not with the detection itself I think.

This the movement code:

```
public void update() {
    // Moves Character or Scrolls Background accordingly.

    if (speedX > 0 && centerX <= 400){
        centerX += speedX;
    }

    if (speedX < 0 && centerX >= 400){
        centerX += speedX;
    }

    if (speedX > 0 && centerX >= 400){
        bg1.setSpeedX(-MOVESPEED);
        bg2.setSpeedX(-MOVESPEED);
    }

    if (speedX < 0 && centerX <= 400){
        bg1.setSpeedX(MOVESPEED);
        bg2.setSpeedX(MOVESPEED);
    }

    if (speedX == 0){
        bg1.setSpeedX(0);
        bg2.setSpeedX(0);
    }

    if(movingRight == true && movingLeft == true ){
        bg1.setSpeedX(0);
        bg2.setSpeedX(0);
    }

    // Handles Jumping
    if (jumped == true) {
        speedY += 1;


    }

    // Prevents going beyond X coordinate of 0
    if (centerX + speedX <= 60) {
        centerX = 61;
    }
    rect.setRect(centerX - 47, centerY - 65, 32, 87);



    centerY += speedY;
}

public void moveRight() {
            speedX = MOVESPEED;     

}

public void moveLeft() {
        speedX = -MOVESPEED;
}

public void stopRight() {
    movingRight = false;
    stop();
}

public void stopLeft() {
    movingLeft = false;
    stop();
}

private void stop() {
    if (movingRight == false && movingLeft == false) {
        speedX = 0;
    }
    if (movingRight == false && movingLeft == true) {
        moveLeft();
    }

    if (movingRight == true && movingLeft == false) {
        moveRight();
    }
  }



public void jump() {
    if (jumped == false) {
        speedY = JUMPSPEED;
        jumped = true;
    }

}
```

and this is the collision code:

```
  public void checkCollision(Rectangle rect){
    if (rect.intersects(r)){
        if(Player.movingRight){
        Player.centerX = tileX + 11;
        Player.speedX =0;
        }

        if(Player.movingLeft){
        Player.centerX = tileX + 89;
        Player.speedX = 0;
        }

        if(Player.speedY > 0){
            Player.centerY = tileY - 25;
            Player.speedY = 0;
            Player.jumped = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is very buggy, sometimes the player "teleports" and even falls threw the wall.

Comment: You're probably going through objects because the check isn't being performed fast enough. If your objects are moving too fast, you may need to handle predictive detection in that you need to work out if an object will hit a wall in the next X frames, instead of checking in the frame it actually happens in.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=predictive+hit+detection - far too complicated to explain here and I'm currently working on it myself :P

Comment: please post more code, what does the intersects method do ? what is r ?if you post the whole classes involved it would make it easier for me to understand what is going on in your code :)